# Check if a matrix is an identity matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to check if a matrix is an identity matrix. I know there's a function which check if a matrix is a diagonal matrix, that is, [`isdiag`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isdiag.html). I know I can do the following to check if a matrix `a` is an identity matrix:

```
isequal(a, eye(size(a, 1)))
```

Is there a function like `isdiag` tha does it directly for me?

Comment: You should generally avoid checking for exactness, unless you're working with integers. You should probably do something like `isidentity=@(a,tol) all(abs(a-eye(size(a)))<tol)`. Or `max(max())` instead of `all(max()<)`.

Comment: There is no built-in function. Your approach is good unless you process very large (sparse) matrices where `eye(size(a, 1))` may exceed the memory.

Comment: Hi @nbro you have multiple of your questions still open without an accepted answer.When an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, you're right, but sometimes they do not satisfy me or I forgot to accept, lol :) I will try to have a look in the next days to those and accept the ones that I think deserve to be accepted ;)

Comment: Expecting others to invest time answering your questions, you should also invest the time to give some minimal feedback if your question is answered or not.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I know. But really sometimes I don't have time. What I can ensure is that I will try to me as much clear as possible in my questions. I promise that I will give feedback to all the answers I didn't give to once I have some free time ;)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you don't necessarily want to check for exact equality to the identity matrix. Also using `eye` can potentially take up an unnecessary amount of memory for sufficiently large matrices. I would recommend using `diag` to get around that.

```
isdiag(a) && all(abs(diag(a) - 1) < tolerance)
```

Comment: Note that `isdiag` probably checks for exact diagonality, so it might not be entirely consistent with the second half of your condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(sum(A - eye(size(A,1)) < epsilon)) == 0
```

Subtract by identity and check if any elements are greater than epsilon.